# Google charts - How to move color settings from data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

As my Google charts code below, the color settings are the same for both sets of data in the datasets section.

How can I seperate the styles from the datasets arrays, so styles are from one object or variable?

```
var data = {
labels: [
    new CustomLabel("January", "January 11"),
    new CustomLabel("February", "February 12"),
    new CustomLabel("March", "March 13"),
    new CustomLabel("April", "April 14"),
    new CustomLabel("May", "May 15"),
    new CustomLabel("June", "June 16"),
    new CustomLabel("July", "July 17")],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery you can use [jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

```
var style = {
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
};

var data = {
    labels: [
        new CustomLabel("January", "January 11"),
        new CustomLabel("February", "February 12"),
        new CustomLabel("March", "March 13"),
        new CustomLabel("April", "April 14"),
        new CustomLabel("May", "May 15"),
        new CustomLabel("June", "June 16"),
        new CustomLabel("July", "July 17")],
    datasets: []
};

data.datasets.push($.extend({}, style, {
    label: "My First dataset",
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    })
);

data.datasets.push($.extend({}, style, {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    })
);
```